# How can I define admin role in Loopback 3?

Tags: javascript, json, localhost, loopback

I have this model in customers.json, acls:

```
"acls": [
{
  "accessType": "*",
  "principalType": "ROLE",
  "principalId": "$everyone",
  "permission": "DENY"
},
{
  "accessType": "READ",
  "principalType": "ROLE",
  "principalId": "admin",
  "permission": "ALLOW",
  "through": "RoleMapping"
}
]
```

And i have this user model base on loopback user:

```
{
 "name": "userModel",
 "base": "User",
 ...
}

"relations": {
"roles": {
  "type": "hasMany",
  "model": "Role",
  "foreignKey": "principalId"
}
},
```

I have defined in http://localhost:3000/explorer in RoleMapping:

```
{
 "id": "58b82f1dbd7b9f1a601646cf",
 "principalType": "USER",
 "principalId": "58b82ec9bd7b9f1a601646ce",
 "roleId": "5570fb69a1227c8c039293da"
 }
```

But i always get 401 Unauthorized error when I try to display the customers.
I would be very gradefull if someone could help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you set the Token in the Loopback Explorer?

When you enable the ACL in Loopback you must Login using the end-point **/user/login**

```
{"username":"john", "password": "abc123"}
```

Then copy and paste the **id** from the response into the Token field.